# Why PictureCallback in android camera is never called?

Tags: android, callback, camera, android-camera

I am facing a problem than PictureCallback is never called.
Similar problems on stackoverflow mentioned more complex examples, where we saved a file to system. This simple callback is never called. No matter how much time I give it.

```
public class InbuiltCamera implements PictureCallback {
private static Camera cameraObject;

public InbuiltCamera() {
    cameraObject = openTheCamera();
}

// //////// METHODS/////////////////////
public static Camera openTheCamera() {
    Camera object = null;
    object = Camera.open();
    return object;
}
public static void closeCamera(){
    if (cameraObject != null)
        cameraObject.release();
}

public void snapIt() {
    cameraObject.takePicture(null, null, this);
}

public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera parameter) {
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
```

}

The problem I am facing is that **Hi** is never printed. EVER !!
ie the call back is never called even if I give it enough time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have implemented camera is not correct .please read the documentation for the proper usage of API. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Also i have uploaded a sample camera application for your reference:
https://github.com/shrishmv/CameraTest

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Shrish

Comment: The problem was, Camera object designed by google has a flaw. Callback is called only when a SurfaceView is implemented and a preview MUST be shown. . . btw your code was similar to Google sources at GIT

Answer (score 0):

Never worked with this, but I feeld like it shouldnt be static allt he way through and onPictureTaken should be @Override

Comment: I tried changing from static. The problem still persists.